# DRY way to assign function values to an object

Tags: ruby, dry

I have an empty object that accepts calculated values for each factor. The method is readable but long and ugly. What is a DRY way of doing this?

```
class ReadingScore

  def initialize(reading, score)
    @reading = reading
    @score = score
  end

  def assign_scoring_factors
    @score.heart_rate_factor              = heart_rate_factor
    @score.systolic_pressure_factor       = systolic_pressure_factor
    @score.diastolic_pressure_factor      = diastolic_pressure_factor
    @score.mean_pressure_factor           = mean_pressure_factor
    @score.signal_minimum_factor          = signal_minimum_factor
    @score.signal_average_factor          = signal_average_factor
    …
  end

  def heart_rate_factor
    @reading.heart_rate && (1..10).include?(@reading.heart_rate) ? 0 : 10
  end

  …
end
```

**Update**
The overall purpose of this class is to calculate a score of a reading. I can’t provide all the code because it is a proprietary algorithm for a medical device.

But basically there are *n* factors of a `@reading` that are calculated and then saved to a `@score` object associated with the `@reading`. The sum of the factors is also calculated as a total on the `@score` object. The `@score` object looks like the following:

```
  @score=
    #<Score:0x007faa0b33ec50
     @attributes=
      {"id"=>42,
       "reading_id"=>42,
       "sum_of_factors"=>10,
       "heart_rate_factor"=>10,
       "another_factor"=>0,
       "another_factor"=>0}
```

Comment: Can you provide the code of the entire "empty object"?

Comment: It is the @score object with a lot of factor attributes like you see above.

Comment: The reason I ask is because DRYing one method may not be much of an improvement. I'd look at possibly changing the design. So as much context as possible helps.

Comment: My design knowledge sucks.. I have *ZERO* knowledge there :-(

Comment: I updated the question with a little more context. Sorry I can’t provide much more code…

Comment: What object are these methods in? Can you provide just an outline? What's the name of the class from which the `@score` object was instantiated? Is it simply a value object? Could you use an OpenStruct instead?

Comment: What's the difference between `Score` and `ReadingScore`? They seem to serve a very similar purpose, but it's hard to tell since I can't see the full code.

Comment: There isn’t much difference. I could move the code to Score and it would work fine. That is one of the options I’m considering. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be the best option so far. The first answer to the question started me on this route, but the poster seems to have removed it…

```
  def assign_factors_to_score
    factors.each do |factor|
      @score.public_send("#{factor}=", self.public_send(factor))
    end
  end

  def factors
    %i{factor_a factor_b factor_c factor_d}
  end
```

Comment: As I said, I am not good in OOD. If some one points that my design is wrong,, I accept it blindly. As I don't have much experience. :-)

Comment: Mark is very experienced Software Engineer. So I don't have dare to disobey him.. :-)

Comment: I agree. However, I don’t believe everything needs to be good OOD. Finding the balance between good OOD and pragmatic design is where I generally land. :-)

Comment: You are far better position than me.. I can say. I am just BLIND. Trust me.. :-(

Comment: This is definitely the way to go. The only other thing I can think of is you could use a `method_added` hook to automatically populate the `factors` array, but that might be overkill. I'll make an answer showing how that is done.

Comment: @Max I’ll have to look at `method_added` some more. That is an interesting option but I think a whitelist is probably saner for this (even though it can become overly verbose).

Answer (score 2):

You can automatically populate an array of factors using `method_added`. This combines nicely with dynamic assignment of factors as in your answer.

```
class ReadingScore
  @factors = []

  def self.method_added meth
    @factors << meth if meth =~ /_factor\Z/
  end

  def self.factors
    @factors
  end
end
```

Note that these are class methods, so you would need to use `self.class.factors` when using this in an instance method.

[Here](https://gist.github.com/silverhammermba/12715e45bfe2468d1e5e) is a full implementation in case you do not see how to integrate this code.

Comment: That is a good example of `method_add` in this case. Thanks! I like learning about methods like this. :-)

Comment: Please show me how you would handle the logic in this case and how the score would be altered appropriately. Also @factors is assigned incorrectly. If it is a class variable then `@@` if not it needs to be assigned on `initialize` or it will not work appropriately.

Comment: The logic would work exactly as in the question - by defining methods for each one. `@factors` is not assigned incorrectly - it is a _class_ instance variable. Did you try my code out before downvoting it?

Comment: Did you analyze mine before down voting it? I actually downvoted it because it does not explain how it can be properly used in this case or take into account any of the logic proposed

Comment: I did analyze your code before downvoting - it involves two repetitions of each factor name. See the link in my edited answer for a full code snippet combining my answer with Nate's (as stated at the beginning of my answer). Each factor is named and defined only once, then collected and assigned dynamically.

Comment: @Max fair enough I have removed my downvote. Although I still think that the whole methodology behind his design places logic in places it does not belong.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `delegate`

```
class ReadingScore
  extend Forwardable
  delegate [:heart_rate_factor=, :systolic_pressure_factor=,:diastolic_pressure_factor=,
      :mean_pressure_factor=,:signal_minimum_factor=,:signal_average_factor=] => :@score
  def initialize
    @score = Score.new
  end

  def assign_scoring_factors
    %w(heart_rate_factor systolic_pressure_factor diastolic_pressure_factor mean_pressure_factor signal_minimum_factor signal_average_factor).each do |meth|
      self.send("#{meth}=",self.send(meth))
    end
    self
  end
end
```

but I agree with others that rethinking the whole design might be better here.

You could also use `tap` but the code will look fairly similar to what you have now.

Also I have no idea what a `Score` looks like internally because it seems like it would be better to place this logic inside the `Score` or `Reading` and pass all of this to a method or initializer of `Score`. e.g.

```
class ReadingScore
   def intialize(reading)
     @reading = Reading.new(reading)
     @score = Score.new(@reading)
   end

end
class Reading
  #...
  def heart_rate_score
    heart_rate && (1..10).include?(@reading.heart_rate) ? 0 : 10
  end
  def systolic_pressure_score
    #logic
  end
  def diastolic_pressure_score
    #logic
  end
  def mean_pressure_score
    #logic
  end
  def signal_minimum_score
    #logic
  end
  def signal_average_score
    #logic
  end
end
class Score
  attr_accessor :heart_rate_factor,:systolic_pressure_factor,:diastolic_pressure_factor,
      :mean_pressure_factor,:signal_minimum_factor,:signal_average_factor
   def initialize(reading)
     factorialize(reading)
     self
   end


  private
    def factorialize(reading)
      %w(heart_rate systolic_pressure diastolic_pressure mean_pressure signal_minimum signal_average) do |meth|
        self.send("#{meth}_factor=",reading.send("#{meth}_score")
      end
    end
 end
```

This way your logic is centralized in `Score` and `Reading` and can be avoided in `ReadingScore`. This will make the code easier to trace and will clean up the original class.

Comment: It probably could go in score. I have it in a class called ReadingScore for now with an initializer that sets `@score` and `@reading`.

Comment: This is some neat code, but it fails at DRYness due to repetition of the factor names.

Comment: @Max this is about as DRY as it can be since he has logic based factors. If the factors were simple getter setters then it would be really easy but he needs logic inside them. I am proposing moving the logic to `Score`.

Comment: @NateBird I updated my answer seems like it would be best to move the logic of "scoring" to the reading and set it in score on initialize. The just use `ReadingScore` as a container class for these attributes. At least this is how I would handle it.

Answer (score -1):

you can do it like this, if you insist:

```
def assign_scoring_factors
  %w(heart_rate systolic_pressure diastolic_pressure mean_pressure signal_minimum signal_average).each |f| do
    eval("@score.#{f}.factor = #{f}.factor")
  end
end
```

but this isn't what I'd do.  I'd either leave it moist, or just use a map.